# Is there an option to directly delete rows in ORC file in pyspark or databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, orc

Is there any option to directly delete the rows from ORC files, provided its structure.

I am using Azure Databricks,

With below query i am reading the content of the ORC file, and wanted to delete those

```sql
%sql select * from orc.`/mnt/my-adls-storage/data/app/simple.orc` 
  where field='test'
```

Is there a way to directly remove the rows from orc.

Alternatively,

- 1. I can read the orc as dataframe
- 2. Filter the records to be deleted
- 3. Write back to a new orc file.
- 4. Remove the older one